# Get value from a XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a XML .How to get CustomerSet value from this ?

```
<a:CreditCards>
 <a:CreditCard>
  <a:AccountNumber>1234XXXXXX23XXXX</a:AccountNumber> 
 <a:ExtendedInfo>
  <a:CustomerSet>RC808687</a:CustomerSet> 
 </a:ExtendedInfo>
 </a:CreditCard>
<a:CreditCards>
```

Comment: This XML is poorly formed.  The a prefix is not declared.

Comment: And please post the complete XML. Where is the declaration of the `a` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPath, 
To get CustomerSet value the xpath would be `/CreditCards/CreditCard/ExtendedInfo/CustomerSet`

Comment: What about the XML namespace with the prefix `a:` in the sample XML ??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml("<CreditCards>  <CreditCard>   <AccountNumber>1234XXXXXX23XXXX</AccountNumber>   <ExtendedInfo>   <CustomerSet>RC808687</CustomerSet>   </ExtendedInfo>  </CreditCard> </CreditCards> ");
            XmlNodeList xmlList = xml.SelectNodes("/CreditCards/CreditCard/ExtendedInfo/CustomerSet");
```

Comment: What about the XML namespace with the prefix `a:` in the sample XML ??